# Highlight of selecte item in Listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, highlighting

I am trying to highlight selected item in `listview` using `selector`.
When I touch down and move, an item is highlighted well. But if I just click it, the item is **not highlighted**.

Here is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/item_default" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

I have been investigating this problem, but I can't find the solution yet.

Comment: did you use android:listSelector in your listview?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/item_default"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is the listview XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Can you try to remove listSelector attribute from ListView and put a selector in a ListView layout as a background.